# Android - Global variables - Application error

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm trying to create global variables in my application by creating a subclass in android.app.Application. I've followed some tutorials on the internet, but I can't seem to get it working. Eclipse is not giving me any errors, but when I start the application I get the following error: Unfortunately, Application has stopped.

Another person asked the same question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954154/android-java-global-variables-through-subclass-cant-launch-app), but this solution does not seem to work for me.

Here are my application files, any help would be greatly appreciated!

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.app.app;

import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView mTxtvName;

String cookie;
String username;
Cookie theRealCookie;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.overzichttablayout);

    mTxtvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvName);

    Globals global = (Globals)getApplication();
    String username = global.getVariable("globUsername");
    String cookie = global.getVariable("globCookie");

    mTxtvName.setText(username);
}

}
```

**Globals.java**

```
package com.app.app;

import android.app.Application;

public class Globals extends Application {

private String globCookie = "null";
private String globUsername = "null";

public String getVariable(String someName) {
    if(someName == "globCookie")
    {
        return globCookie;
    }
    else if(someName == "globUsername")
    {
        return globUsername;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setVariable(String someName, String someVariable) {
    if(someName == "globCookie")
    {
        this.globCookie = someVariable;
    }
    else if(someName == "globUsername")
    {
        this.globUsername = someVariable;
    }
}
}
```

**Application Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="OverviewActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"></activity>
</application>
<application android:name="Globals" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" />

</manifest>
```

**Log Cat** (shortend)

```
08:51:53.783: D/AndroidRuntime(1650): Shutting down VM
08:51:53.783: W/dalvikvm(1650): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08:51:53.863: E/AndroidRuntime(1650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: As much as I realize it doesn't really relate to your question... Are you sure that you want to do things this way? There's a few pretty big holes in your code here, among them, grabbing a variable by sending a string of it's name as a parameter. Also, having locally and globally scoped variables with the same name (do you realize that cookie goes out of scope as soon as you assign it a value?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error is because you declared a second `<application />` tag

You should have the `Globals` declared in the first `<application />`tag

```
<application
    android:name="Globals" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

And this line, delete:

```
<application android:name="Globals" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot create two applications in one single Manifest.

Instead add `android:name="Globals"` to the first `Application` tag itself.

If this is not the reason for error, post the whole logcat message.

Answer (score 0):

i think it because you set textview with null value.
you can't compare two string with == operator, you can use equals() function instead.
ie. someName.equals("globCookie")

Answer (score 0):

Reason for exception: two application tags found in Manifest file. To rectify it replace Manifest line

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

with

```
<application 
android:name="Globals"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

And delete this line :

```
<application android:name="Globals" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

ALso you are trying to call globCookie and globUsername before they are intialized. You may want to override `onCreate()` in Globals and set globCookie and globUsername to some default values.